# Synonym request: CA -> certificate-authority

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are only two questions tagged [ca](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ca), both referring to [certificate-authority](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certificate-authority). Unless there is another important meaning of CA I suggest a synonym. The synonym [has already been suggested](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/certificate-authority/synonyms), so please upvote the request (I can't, lacking the rep required) [there](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/certificate-authority/synonyms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synonym set; tags have been merged.